# Error executing SQL using Perl

Tags: oracle, perl, unix

I am trying to execute the open source code which finds the list of tables involved in SQL.

I am working on [*Retrieve table names from Oracle queries*](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/03/retrieve-table-names-from-oracle.html).

I understood the expressions and commands to some extent and tried it.

Details of my execution:

1. `GetTable.pl` file
   same as in the link
2. `test.sql` file
   I didn't use the one in link. Instead I had only a single SQL for testing.
   `SELECT emp_name FROM load_tables.temp`;
3. Executed in Strawberry Perl

I tried the following

```
$ perl GetTable.pl

Usage : GetTable <sql query file>
```

```
$ perl test.sql

Can't locate object method "FROM" via package "load_tables" (perhaps you forgot to load "load_tables"?) at test.sql line 1
```

Can someone help me in executing it? I'm not sure if there is problem with code as I could see two people have executed successfully.

#### Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

#Function which gets the table names and formats and prints them.

sub printTable {
    my $tab = shift;
    $tab =~ s/,\s+/,/g;
    $tab =~ s/\s+,/,/g;

    my @out = split( /,/, $tab );

    foreach ( @out ) {
        $_ =~ s/ .*//;
        print $opr, $_, "\n";
    }
}

# Function which gets the indivdual queries and separtes the table
# names from the queries. Sub-Queries, co-related queries, etc..
# will also be handled.

sub process {
    local $opr;
    my $line = shift;
    $line =~ s/\n/ /g;

    if ( $line =~ m/^\s*(select|delete)/i ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/^\s*select/i ) {
            $opr = "SELECT: ";
        }
        else {
            $opr = "DELETE: ";
        }
        if ( $line =~ m/from.*where/i ) {
            while ( $line =~ m/from\s+(.*?)where/ig ) {
                &printTable( $1 );
            }
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ m/from.*;/i ) {
            while ( $line =~ m/from\s+(.*);/ig ) {
                &printTable( $1 );
            }
        }
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/^\s*update\s+(\w+)\s+/i ) {
        $opr = "UPDATE: ";
        &printTable( $1 );
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/^\s*insert\s+into\s+(\w+)\s+/i ) {
        $opr = "INSERT: ";
        &printTable( $1 );
    }
}

#The main function which reads the files and reads the
#query into a variable and sends it to process function.

if ( @ARGV != 1 ) {
    print "Usage: GetTable <sql query file>\n";
    exit 1;
}

open QFILE, $ARGV[0] or die "File $ARGV[0]: $! \n";

my $flag  = 0;
my $query = "";
my $conds = "select|insert|update|delete";

while ( <QFILE> ) {

    next if ( /^$/ );

    if ( $flag == 1 ) {
        $query .= $_;
        if ( /;\s*$/ ) {
            $flag = 0;
            &process( $query );
        }
    }
    elsif ( /^\s*($conds).*;\s*/i ) {
        &process( $_ );
    }
    elsif ( /^\s*($conds)/i ) {
        $flag  = 1;
        $query = $_;
    }
}

close QFILE;
```

Answer (score 5):

Two important skills to learn as a programmer are a) accuracy in following instructions and b) reading the error message carefully.

You started by running `GetTable.pl`. But that program requires a parameter (the name of an SQL file to analyse) and the error message tried to tell you that.

I don't know why, but instead of doing what the error message told you to do (which would have been to run `perl GetTable.pl test.sql`) you decided to ask Perl to run your SQL file.

The second error message you got was the Perl compiler trying to make sense of the SQL that you asked it to run. But the Perl compiler doesn't understand SQL, it understands Perl. So it's no surprise that it got confused.

To fix it, do what your first error message suggested—run the command

```
$ perl GetTable.pl test.sql
```